# Can we combine inpatient with outpatient days in survival/multi study?

Tags: survival

Let's say we have follow up data for patients that experience different states (diagnosis, treatment 1, treatment 2, etc.). These patients can leave the hospital or clinic and revisit it. When analyzing survival/multi state data can we as well take into account the outpatient days for each entity and model it as a separate state?

@ EDIT: I added an example data for a wider perspective of my problem:

Let's say we have data:

```
id in         out        duration state
1  2010/02/04 2010/02/10 6        diagnosis
1  2010/05/24 2010/05/26 2        treatment
1  2011/11/13 2011/11/27 14       treatment
```

and we know that nothing occured between inpatient days. Generally I am interested in modelling transition probabilities, ELOS, discrete simulation etc. I alrieady achieved it using above patient data format and semi-markov parametric survival models. My question is: can we as well model the time when the patient was out of hospital? For example we would extend the data into a format where we create new state and it desribes the breaks (outpatient days):

```
id in         out        duration state
1  2010/02/04 2010/02/10 6        diagnosis
1  2010/02/11 2010/05/23 101      outpatient
1  2010/05/24 2010/05/26 2        treatment
1  2010/05/27 2011/11/12 534      outpatient
1  2011/11/13 2011/11/27 14       treatment
```

So I can get the probability of taking a break (outpatient days) for a given patient characteristics and given state that he's currently in or he's visited.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this question cuold benefit a lot from more context and detail.E. g. what exactly do you mean by "a seperate state"?

Comment: As @Bernhard said, more details would help a lot. Multi-state survival analysis is certainly possible, but the way to set it up right depends a lot on the specific situation you are trying to understand.